# Pure HTML/CSS solution for making a whole body background clickable

Tags: html, css

I would like to have this whole div (which occupies the background of the page) to be fully clickable,

```
<div style="position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index: -1; background: url() center center no-repeat; width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <a href='http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-8.jpg' target='_blank' style="display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-8.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

I have this right at the start of the body, and it does give a background to the whole document, but it is completely non-clickable despite giving in a `display:block` along with full width and height.

is there a pure html/css solution for this?

Comment: With HTML5 we no longer have to worry about anchor tags being inside of the divs. Try wrapping your div with your anchor. That being said if you wanted the code to be cleaner add a little js to make your div clickable.

Comment: cheers. I just able to fix this by putting the z-index to 1 instead of -1;

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-8.jpg">Hello world!!!</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
background: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-8.jpg) center center no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height:100vh;
}
```